# Having trouble Alt-Tabbing to matplotlib figure on OSX Lion

Tags: matplotlib, osx-lion

This wasn't a problem for me on OSX Leopard as each matplotlib figure window was represented with a rocket-ship like icon, but when a now on Lion when a figure pops up there is no symbol or icon associated with it that shows up in the list of applications I can switch to using Alt-Tab. This may sound trivial but it's an important part of my work flow.

Is there a solution to this? I keep reading about these backends and I wonder if I change the backend for OSX Lion something like an X11 or Quartz icon will represent each figure...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a X11-related backend (GTK or some configurations of Qt), then all of the figures fall into a X11 application and you can't alt-tab between them (although you can right click on the X icon and select the figure).

If you are not using an X11 backend and all your figures are coming from the same process (e.g. interactive plotting in ipython), then they all fall under the same 'rocket-ship' icon, so no alt-tab either. If you are using the 'osx' backend or the 'qt4' backend (when using qt-mac, not qt-x11), then you should have one rocket-ship per process. Note that the 'osx' backend only starts the rocket-ship when the figure is created, while the 'qt4' backend starts it as soon as pylab/matplotlib are imported.

I just tried under Snow Leopard and Lion and the behaviour was identical.

Comment: Thanks but there is no no rocket ship or X11 so I can't even access any figure at all, as it is hidden behind my Emacs fullscreen configuration...

Comment: That is rather strange. Which backend are you using?

Comment: I tried MacOSX (same as current behavior), TkAgg (error), and I don't have the rest installed (pyqt, pygtk, etc.)